# How to reuse a list in OWL?

Tags: owl, semantic-web

Let's say I'm defining a class *Alcohol*:

```
:Alcohol rdf:type owl:Class ;
         owl:equivalentClass [ 
             rdf:type owl:Class ;
             owl:oneOf ( :Vodka :Champagne :Bourbon :Tequila :Whiskey ) ] .
```

But I want members to be distinct:

```
[ rdf:type owl:AllDifferent ;
  owl:distinctMembers ( :Bourbon :Vodka :Champagne :Whiskey :Tequila ) ] .
```

How can I write those two statements without repeating the list?

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK, not possible in OWL. In RDF you could try to reuse the first blank node of the list but then you'd loose the fancy Turtle shortform for lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, use blank node reference:

```
:Alcohol a owl:Class ;
    owl:equivalentClass [ a owl:Class ;
                          owl:oneOf _:b0 ] .

[ a owl:AllDifferent ;
  owl:distinctMembers  _:b0 ] .

_:b0 rdf:first :Vodka ;
    rdf:rest ( :Champagne :Bourbon :Tequila :Whiskey ) .
```